# Notify button ActionEvent from GridCell

Tags: gridview, javafx, controlsfx

I have a GridView with custom GridCell that contains a button.

```
private class MyGridCell extends GridCell<modelclass> {
     @FXML private Button button;
     ...    


protected void updateItem(modelclass item, boolean empty) {
        ...

       button.setOnAction(event -> {

           //I need to call a controller method

           ParentController.doSomething(item);

       });
```

I need to send message a method from controller or notify with some event the action occurred.

Do you know how to access to the controller of the GridView to call o method

or

Detect the ActionEvent from the controller class.

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't the cell created from inside the controller? Just pass a reference to the controller to the cell instance. Or if this is an inner class inside the controller class, you can just call the method directly.

Comment: I guess my point is that you need to show more context in the question; where is the `GridView` defined and where do you set its cell factory, etc.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, I'm very stupid. I passed hours searching a solution, and result that  it is an inner class.